# How do I send a user looking for sub.example.com to example.com:8082?

Tags: nginx

How do I send a user looking for sub.example.com to example.com:8082? I use Nginx as proxy for Apache.
I have a service running on port 8082 and want the user to access it via the subdomain

Regards

Anders

Comment: I think you're looking for what in jargon would be a reverse proxy configuration and the nginx [`proxy_pass`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) directive.

Answer (score 0):

First check DNS settings so sub.example.com has A/AAAA records pointing to your proxy server's public IP. And make Apache listen with a virtual host on example.com:8082.

Now we have to possible solutions. Your question did not make clear which you prefer:

---

**Option A: proxy_pass**

User should see sub.example.com in his browser while in the background the page is fetched from the Apache from that special port.

Add an nginx vhost config with a server listening on the sub.example.com domain (I assume port 80/443?) and a location section to pass traffic to example.com:8082:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name sub.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass       http://example.com:8082;
            proxy_set_header Host      $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

    }
```

This is just a rough guide. There is certainly more to take care of. Please provide more details to get a more detailed answers.

---

**Option B: redirect**

User will open sub.example.com but then get's redirected so he sees example.com:8082 in his browser.

Add an nginx vhost config with a server listening on the sub.example.com domain (I assume port 80/443?) and redirect example.com:8082:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name sub.example.com;

        return 301 http://example.com:8082;

    }
```

---

This is just a rough guide. There are more details for sure, you need to take care of. Provide more information to get better answers.

Comment: It is the traccar gps tracking server that is in question. the subdomain should only point at the port nothing else

Comment: If by `point at` you mean `redirect`, then try option B.